# How can I bypass 'nowsecure.nl' via the Requests library in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, cloudflare, bypass

I would like to access *nowsecure.nl* with using the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library in Python. But I don't want to use *undetected_chromedriver*.

I’ve came up with this as an example:

```
import os, time, requests
from undetected_chromedriver import v2 as uc

def clear():
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system("cls")
    else:
        os.system("clear")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clear()
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://rblxwild.com")
    time.sleep(2.2)

    cf_clearance = driver.get_cookie("cf_clearance").get("value")
    __cf_bm = driver.get_cookie("__cf_bm").get("value")

    print(f"cf_clearance: {cf_clearance}")
    print(f"__cf_bm: {__cf_bm}")

    driver.quit()

    Headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "Host": "rblxwild.com",
        "From": "https://rblxwild.com",
        "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"92\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"92\"",
        "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
        "cookie": f"cf_clearance={cf_clearance}; __cf_bm={__cf_bm}",
    }

    Session = requests.Session()
    r = Session.post("https://rblxwild.com/crash", headers=Headers, cookies={"cf_clearance": cf_clearance, "__cf_bm": __cf_bm})
    print(r.status_code)

    os.abort()
```

How can I bypass it via Requests?